# Can loop quantum gravity use known techniques to cure the fermion doubling problem?

Tags: loop-quantum-gravity

It is well known that LQG has a fermion doubling problem and therefore cannot include chiral fermions.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01232

However, there are already many known techniques to dealing with fermion doubling, such as staggered fermions. So can't one just extend staggered fermions into LQG to cure the problem? Would doing so make LQG be able to include chiral fermions?